# Take Screenshot Before any ARCore model is rendered

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm using Screenshot code to take a screenshot of the screen which is working fine but its also taking the arcore models with it. Is there a way to take a screenshot before models are rendered?

I tried to `SetActive(false)` then take a screenshot then `SetActive(true)`, it does work but there's a noticeable difference i.e. model disappears than reappears.

### Update: This is a script applied on ScreenShotCamera and it is updated after removing all the bugs (thanks to @Shingo), feel free to use it it's working properly

```
using GoogleARCore;
using OpenCVForUnitySample;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class SnapshotCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    Camera snapCam;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text text;
    public RenderTexture mRenderTexture;
    int resWidth=480;
    int resHeight=800;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void initialize(ARBackgroundRenderer background, Material material)
    {
        background = new ARBackgroundRenderer();
        snapCam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        background.backgroundMaterial = material;
        background.camera = snapCam;
        background.mode = ARRenderMode.MaterialAsBackground;
        if (snapCam.targetTexture == null)
        {
            snapCam.targetTexture = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
        }
        else
        {
            snapCam.targetTexture.height = resHeight;
            snapCam.targetTexture.width = resWidth;
            //resHeight = snapCam.targetTexture.height;
            //resWidth = snapCam.targetTexture.width;
        }
        background.camera.cullingMask = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default");
        //snapCam.CopyFrom(background.camera);

        snapCam.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void TakeSnapShot()
    {
        snapCam.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (snapCam.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            snapCam.cullingMask = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default");
            if (ARCoreBackgroundRenderer.screenShot == null)
                ARCoreBackgroundRenderer.screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            snapCam.Render();
            RenderTexture.active = snapCam.targetTexture;
            ARCoreBackgroundRenderer.screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
            ARCoreBackgroundRenderer.screenShot.Apply();

            snapCam.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            HandPoseRecognition.captureTexture = false;

            //string name = string.Format("{0}_Capture{1}_{2}.png", Application.productName, "{0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
            //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Permission result: " + NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery(ARCoreBackgroundRenderer.screenShot, Application.productName + " Captures", name));
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps I was a little ambiguous, what u mentioned in the comment has already been resolved thanks to you but the problem now is.
I'll show you the images: 
**These are the 2 cameras I have:**
[image]

**This is what my Main (ARCore Camera) shows**

[image]

**And this is what the (ScreenShot Camera) Shows**
[image]

Comment: Post your code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use layer, put every arcore models in one layer (eg. ARLAYER), then set camera's culling mask to avoid these models.

Pseudo code:

```
// Set models' layer
foreach (GameObject arcoreModel in arcoreModels)
     arcoreModel.layer = ARLAYER;

// Set camera's culling mask
camera.cullingMask = ~(1 << ARLAYER);
camera.Render();
```

---

Create screenshot camera from another camera

```
var go = new GameObject("screenshotcamera");
// Copy transform
go.transform.position = mainCamera.transform.position.
...
// Copy camera
var screenshotcamera= go.AddComopnent<Camera>();
screenshotcamera.CopyFrom(mainCamera);
```

---

**Update with your script**

```
snapCam = GetComponent<Camera>();
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where do u think I should do this?
and @shingo if u can please elaborate a bit more? thank you!

Comment: I understand the layer concepts with this you can put unnecessary objects on the other layer and hide it but they will be hidden from the camera too, not just from the Screenshot. I need the models to be visible on camera but not on screenshot.

Comment: You can create a dedicated camera to take a screenshot, see the update.

Comment: Or set back cullingMask after the screenshot is taken.

Comment: I have tried the code it is no different than before it still takes the model's image
If its possible to create another camera specific for screenshot and have it at the back of main Camera? Something like that?

Comment: I'm not sure what code you have tried, if you try all the codes in my answer, it should work. The main camera can see every layers and the screenshot camera can not see models.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I updated my Code in the question, please have a look.

Comment: I changed the renderTexture.active to render object created or even the screenshotcamera.targetTexture but nothing seems to work it always gives black Image. Totally lost If u= can help me I have been trying many things but none seems to work. Note: I am building in android phone not Unity app heard there's a difference. Thank you!

Comment: Check the example of [RenderTexture.active](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture-active.html) and [Camera.Render](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.Render.html)

Comment: I have applied it as it is but the problem is that it gives Black picture maybe the fact that another camera is not able to view from the device's camera as 1 camera (ARCore) already is hence the other camera is not getting any content...........
I followed a tutorial and created RenderTexture which I applied on secondary camera and the problem still persists it takes image of empty scene when it should be taking image through device's camera. Any help in that?

Comment: If u didn't understand the problem. The problem now is that the secondary camera is viewing the game view when I need it to view the device's camera view

Comment: Shingo if you can bother this one last time, I would really appreciate it Thank you!

Comment: May you update your post to the latest modifcation?

Comment: Updated the Code, please have a look. I explained you the current problem (the screenshot is being taken of the game View when this is an ARCore App i need the screenshot of device camera).... Note: I cannot take the screenshot of the ARCore Camera because it includes the model in it.

Comment: Look at the first 2 lines in `Awake`, `snapCam` and `ARCoreBackgroundRenderer.m_Camera` are identical. I change the 1st line to `GetComponent<Camera>()`, attach the script to the screenshotCamera, the script works well, see my updated image. The right box is put in `IgnoredByCamera` layer, and it's gone in the screenshot image.

Comment: Shingo, I have updated the code as you told me, please check the section below the updated code I have added some pictures. This is the issue I was talking about in the previous 2 comments

Comment: I see there is only 1 model in the 2nd picture, so if it needs to be excluded from the screenshot camera, then nothing left (except the image from your device camera). So if you want to take photo with unity, take a look at `WebCamTexture` or `ARBackgroundRenderer` in unity document.

Comment: I did study WebCamTexture but when I create an instance and `webcam.Play()` it, it pauses the ARCore Camera since both of these are cameras but different and the `ARBackgroundRenderer` I have tried to study it alot but no luck in it either, you can't just get the texture off of it you have to read it through ReadPixels and that's what I'm currently doing and that has the model in it. **and you got some part right** yes there is a model in the 2nd picture which is hidden but the problem is that 2nd camera is not acting like device's camera its acting like gameview Camera

Comment: I just want to make sure that by **device's camera** i mean your camera like from which you view the world i.e. selfie camera (just an example) and from **gameview** i mean the regular camera that shows Unity world and since that world is empty it shows just the default color or the color of the sky

Comment: I guess you cannot find the answer to it either, well thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: I think I have already given an answer, if you just want to take the photo from your device camera, you can use `WebCamTexture` or `ARBackgroundRenderer`, you can even read the image data from that **First Person Camera**, it has an `ARBackgroundRenderer` attached, and the [backgroundTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.ARBackgroundRenderer-backgroundTexture.html) is the photo, you don't need to create another camera at all, set it as the active RenderTexture and call ReadPixels to get the data.

Comment: If I do that, we are back to square one the model will be included in the picture which was the initial problem

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help and determination shingo, I studied about ARBackgroundRenderer and I was able to finally do it. I'll update the code for everyone to get help and again Thank you for your struggle.. really....